# What does "He is a ruin of his former self" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **ruin**
>
> b. One that has been extensively damaged or harmed: ***He is a ruin of
>   his former self.***

I came across this sentence under the definition of the word 'ruin' in [the free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruin). I don't quite understand what it means. Does it mean: *he has been ruined once before or something*?

Comment: Ancient buildings ravaged by time, some of the walls tumbled down, etc, are called **ruins**.  So he's but  the crumbling remains of his former self.  A building that has been destroyed by fire or bombing or natural disaster is said to be **in ruins**.  *When we visited, most of the village was in ruins.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I know what the word ruin means, but unsure the phrase "a ruin of his former self".

Comment: It is simply a metaphorical|figurative use. He is being likened to such a building.

Comment: A 'wreck' can convey a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other ways to say this are

> He is a broken man.
>
> He is a shadow of his former self.

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/broken) has this example

> He died a broken man and was buried only a couple of miles away from
>   his birthplace.

The words "ruin" and "broken" are figurative (although "ruined" and "broke" could mean financially). There is also the similar figurative phrase

> She died from a broken heart.

Answer (score 1):

The cliché expression is: a shadow of [his, her, your] former self.

It's in the dictionary: [Cambridge Dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-shadow-of-your-former-self)

- **He is a shadow of his self**. [not like he was at all before, either mentally or physically. Completely different]

**By substituting ruin for shadow, a literary cliché is avoided.**

The idea is that now the person is a ruin (something spoiled as in an old house) compared to the way they were before.